# How do you download orders where all batches will meet the condition?

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables in the mssql database: orders and batches. Each order can have many lots. The cost is kept in each lot. I would like to draw all orders, where the cost of EACH of his lot is higher than eg 100. If in any part of the order the cost is not greater than 100, this will disqualify the order. Is it possible to do so in one query?

Comment: We can approximate an answer based on this, but it would be better if you share your table structure with us.

Comment: yes it would be better if you can share your table structure and desired output layout.

Comment: ok guys, the solution from the first post is enough for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach uses aggregation by order to check each lot:

```
SELECT o.id
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN batches b
    ON o.batch_id = b.id
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN b.cost <= 100 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method is to use `MIN()`:

```
SELECT b.order_id
FROM batches b
GROUP BY b.order_id
HAVING MIN(b.cost) >= 100;
```

If you want the order information:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where not exists (select 1 from batches b where b.order_id = o.order_id and b.cost < 100);
```